# Rest query for nested field

Tags: json, rest

I am calling rest to get User that is located in another table.

This is the response if i only do: /sdata/api/dynamic/-/salesteammembers('2ae46c09-5701-4d8f-b318-6b994ec07fd2')

```
{
  "$key": "2ae46c09-5701-4d8f-b318-6b994ec07fd2",
  "$descriptor": "",
  "TenantId": "7b6791d5-8658-44e5-86bc-8181735d0bf7",
  "CreatedOn": "\/Date(1368495720000-0700)\/",
  "UpdatedOn": "\/Date(1368495720000-0700)\/",
  "ExternalId": null,
  "ExternalReference": null,
  "SyncHashKey": null,
  "SyncEndpoint_Id": 0,
  "SyncEndpointTick": 0,
  "EntityStatus": "Active",
  "SalesPersonCode": "Sage100SPCode",
  "Title": "Sales Person 1",
  "PhoneWork": "555-555-1234",
  "PhoneMobile": "555-555-5678",
  "EmailWork": "sage100User@sage.com",
  "User": {
    "$key": "f8671467-419b-4def-a255-6b4bfb5c06bd"
  },
  "GoalPeriods": {}
}
```

but in addition i want to get the data located in the table that in the first response had the field User and a key

```
"User": {
    "$key": "f8671467-419b-4def-a255-6b4bfb5c06bd"
  }
```

any tips on the url query? I have tried /sdata/api/dynamic/-/salesteammembers('2ae46c09-5701-4d8f-b318-6b994ec07fd2')/user('f8671467-419b-4def-a255-6b4bfb5c06bd') and bunch of other combinations but none of them worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: You didn't even tell us what the website is

Comment: i am testing on localhost

Comment: also, i did /sdata/api/dynamic/-/salesteammembers('2ae46c09-5701-4d8f-b318-6b994ec07fd2')?include=user('52bf3ce5-24dc-4d60-8d30-b5c2ca155719') but no luck

Comment: Which REST service do you call? Please point us to the description of the service so we can figure out who the URLs are constructed.